# Zombie.js - How to check the result of a form submission on DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, zombie.js

**Goal:** Using Mocha, Zombie.js, and Mongoose, I am trying to test a signup form. I want to make sure that the user is added to the database using the following code:

```
describe('User Signup', function() {

  before(function(done) { //setup db connection and browser

    conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost', function(err) {

      browser = new Browser({site: 'http://localhost:3000'});
      done();

    });

  });

  before(function(done) { //go to signup page

    browser.visit('/user/signup', done);

  });

  it('can signup a new user', function(done) {

    browser.fill("input[name='username']", 'johnDoe');
    browser.fill("input[name='pwd']", 'password');
    browser.fill("input[name='pwd_retype']", 'password');
    browser.fill("input[name='city']", 'New York, NY');
    browser.pressButton('#signup-submit').then(function() {

      chai.assert.isOk(browser.success);

      UserModel.findOne({username: 'johnDoe'}, function(er, usr) {

        chai.assert.ifError(er);
        chai.assert.isNotNull(usr); //check if user was added to DB
        done();

      });

    });

  });

});
```

**Problem:** The user gets added to the DB, but it gets added as a blank user (no username, password, etc). I checked the router that handles the request and put a `console.log` printing the username to see if zombie.js fills out the form fields, but the fields print empty. I get the following output:
[image]

So when the mocha test runs the first time, I get the line `SAVE ATTEMPT FOR:` with a blank username value. However, when I change a document and save, then I get the output again except with the correct value `SAVE ATTEMPT FOR: johnDoe`.

I don't understand why the request is sent again when I save my js files. Of course this happens way after my tests evaluate. Anyone have ideas as to what could be the problem?